# Python Numpy Sort rows

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

Very new to Python so please bear with me here. I am trying to sort an array that I have imported into python with numpy.sort:

```
 guy = numpy.sort(sasBody, axis=-0)
```

The first column is a column of strings, so I would like to alphabetically sort the array. The problem I am having is that it does sort the first column, however all the numbers associated with the prior rows are now not connected to its correct first column counterpart.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `-0` instead of just `0`?

Comment: Very new to python, found it on the web and am copy pasting. I don't really know what the axis bit does anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`np.lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) though in case of strings that may not work. As a work around, you may use [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

```
>>> a
array([['xyz', 0],
       ['abc', 5],
       ['ijk', 10]], dtype=object)
>>> i = np.argsort(a[:,0])
>>> a[i]
array([['abc', 5],
       ['ijk', 10],
       ['xyz', 0]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry a little bit more digging found me the answer 
 `guy = sasBody[np.argsort(sasBody[:, 0])]`